# Deserialize dynamic object from request to strong type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement API endpoint that should allow dynamic object in request body.

Example of body 1:

```
{
  "type": "CallStart",
  "attributes": {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Time": "09:15"
  }
}
```

Example of body 2:

```
{
  "type": "CallEnd",
  "attributes": {
      "Name": "Test",
      "SendFeedback": true
  }
}
```

So, I created model for this:

```
public class CommandRequest
{
    public CommandType Type { get; set; }
    public dynamic Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have tried to write something like this

```
[HttpPost("id")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Commands([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] CommandRequest requestBody)
{
    object command = null;
    switch (requestBody.Type)
    {
        case CommandType.CallStart:
            command = new Command<CallStartAttributes>
            {
                Type = requestBody.Type,
                Id = id,
                Attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallStartAttributes>(requestBody.Attributes)
            };
            break;
        case CommandType.CallEnd:
            command = new Command<CallEndAttributes>
            {
                Type = requestBody.Type,
                Id = id,
                Attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallEndAttributes>(requestBody.Attributes)
            };
            break;
        default: throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    await _mediator.Send(command);
    return Ok();
}
```

All models

```
public class Command<TAttributes> : IRequest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public CommandType Type { get; set; }
    public TAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
}
public class CallStartAttributes
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
public class CallEndAttributes
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool SendFeedback { get; set; }
}
```

It doesn't work in this way. Error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Core.Features.CallStartAttributes>(string)' has some invalid arguments

How can I deserialise dynamic object to strong type?

I would prefer to not change this

```
public dynamic Attributes { get; set; }
```

to this

```
public string Attributes { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **DeserializeObject** always expects a string, why not serialize dynamic to string. Perhaps bit hacky but this would work:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallEndAttributes>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
requestBody.Attributes))

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallStartAttributes>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
requestBody.Attributes))
```

Minimal reproducible code of your problem that I tried:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
    
namespace SO
{
    public enum CommandType
    {
        CallStart, CallEnd
    }
    public class CommandRequest
    {
        public CommandType Type { get; set; }
        public dynamic Attributes { get; set; }
    }
    public class Command<TAttributes>
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public CommandType Type { get; set; }
        public TAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
    }
    public class CallStartAttributes
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }
    public class CallEndAttributes
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool SendFeedback { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildCommand();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void BuildCommand()
        {
            CommandRequest requestBody1 = new CommandRequest() { Type = CommandType.CallStart, Attributes = new { Name = "TestStart", Time = "some time" } };
            CommandRequest requestBody2 = new CommandRequest() { Type = CommandType.CallEnd, Attributes = new { Name = "TestEnd", SendFeedback = true } };


            var command1 = new Command<CallStartAttributes>
            {
                Id = "1",
                Type = requestBody1.Type,
                Attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallStartAttributes>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody1.Attributes))
            };
            var command2 = new Command<CallEndAttributes>
            {
                Id = "2",
                Type = requestBody2.Type,
                Attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallEndAttributes>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody2.Attributes))
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm..I tried at my end and it worked. I hope I didn't make any wrong assumptions about your input (requestBody). I am posting the code that I tried in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Json.Net JObject attribute. check https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm. Then get the particular values you're looking for.